# How can I trigger a daily api call in Google Apps Script without overwriting previous day's values?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a function in Google Apps Script that fetches to a serverless api I created which returns our company's Facebook ad spend for the previous day.

```
function fetchAdData() {
  const url = SERVERLESS_ENDPOINT
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const json = response.getContentText();
  const GBP = Intl.NumberFormat("en-GB", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "GBP",
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  });
  let data = JSON.parse(json)
  let result = data.map((ad) => {
    return [ad.date, ad.campaign, GBP.format(ad.spend)]
  })
return result
}
```

I'm using a macro and daily trigger to make the function run daily to give us a daily rundown of the previous day's campaigns and spend:

```
function DailyAdSpendFetch() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const spreadsheet = ss.getSheetByName('ADSPEND');
  let data = '=fetchAdData()'
  spreadsheet.appendRow([data])
};
```

The functions work as expected but are overwriting the previous day's values whenever it is called. So for example instead of having:

| Date | Campaign | Spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-26 | AD_CAMPAIGN_1 | £100 |
| 2022-09-27 | AD_CAMPAIGN_2 | £200 |
| 2022-09-28 | AD_CAMPAIGN_3 | £300 |

I'm getting:

| Date | Campaign | Spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-28 | AD_CAMPAIGN_3 | £300 |
| 2022-09-28 | AD_CAMPAIGN_3 | £300 |
| 2022-09-28 | AD_CAMPAIGN_3 | £300 |

I've tried setting the value instead of appending the row :

```
function DailyAdSpendFetch() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var spreadsheet = ss.getSheetByName('ADSPEND');
  let data = '=fetchAdData()'
  let lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow()
  let activeCell = spreadsheet.getRange(`A${lastRow}`);
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(activeCell);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue([data]);
};
```

But I get the same result.

This is my first time working in Google Apps Script so any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do. All in one function. You get the last row of the sheet and add 1 as starting point to set the values. Also the `Intl.NumberFormat` changes your number to formatted text so you cannot use it in you're sheet to sum. Do the formatting in you're sheet.

```
function fetchAdData() {
  const url = SERVERLESS_ENDPOINT
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).map((ad) => {
    return [ad.date, ad.campaign, ad.spend]
  })

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('ADSPEND');

  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```